# Installing Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 7 (32bit)

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, visual-studio-2019

Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 (32bit), 
Intel Core Duo(TM)2 (2.2GHZ), 
4GB Ram

I am trying to help a friend of mine install Visual 2019 Community Edition. He already went through the process, but there is zero sign of Visual Studio, it doesn't even show up in Programs and Features.

When we run the installer again, it says that its download and installed, and processes for a bit and then disappears. We tried going back to a recovery point and trying again, but it still says it's downloaded and installed. And there is still zero sign of its existence.

Windows 7 is fully updated. It's a fresh install and has barely anything on it at the moment.

EDIT:

Microsoft Visual Studio / Installer, appears in the Programs Folder, with a bunch of files in it. This is the only folder, there is no Visual Studio executable.

Tried to delete it and start over, and it started over, but it has the same problem, it sits at the "Almost done ... Getting everything ready" screen, and then vanishes. Nothing else happens, nothing is installed.

Comment: See the list of [VS2019 requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements), especially regarding the versions of Windows (Home Premium+) and .NET Framework (4.5+).

Comment: So if you manually run the visual studio executable, what happens, edit your question with this vital information.

Comment: in my case i saw exactly the same symptoms (on W7 64-bit); i realised that only .net framework 4.5.1 was installed; once i updated it to 4.5.2, the VS installer seemed to work as expected.